# Proving that the function f is constant, mean value theorem, derivatives

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, derivatives

Having the following inequality, for a real-valued function $f$ which is twice differentiable:

$f(a+h)-f(a)\geq f(a)-f(a-h)$ for any $a \in\mathbf{R}$, $h > 0$.

and assuming that $f$ is bounded, I see on a graph that $f$ is constant but I can't prove it properly.
I tried to prove that $f'(x)=0$ for all $x$ in the domain of $f$. I also tried to assume it wasn't true and use the Mean Value Theorem but it's not convincing, I see the inequality above looks like first derivatives but I can't use it...

Can you hint me please?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

$$
\frac{f(a+h)-2f(a)+f(a-h)}{h^2} \xrightarrow{h \to 0}{\, f''(a)} \quad \text{(by L’Hôpital’s rule)}.
$$
Actually, your condition looks like a convexity condition at any point, and convex functions are either unbounded or constant on the whole $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Actually, the RHS of that equality should just be $f''(a)$ - there is no '2'. (I am not able to edit your answer directly for some reason.)

Answer (score 0):

Show the contrapositive, that if $f$ is not constant but satisfies the given condition, then $f$ is not bounded.

If $f$ is not constant then there exist $p,q$ with, say, $p<q$ and $f(p)\ne f(q)$.  I'll consider only the case $f(p)<f(q)$, leaving the case $f(p)>f(q)$ to you.

Set $x_k=p+k(q-p)$.  Taking $a=x_k$ and $h=q-p$ in the hypothesis gives
$$ f(x_{k+1})-f(x_k) \ge f(x_k) - f(x_{k-1}) $$
By induction, if $k\ge 0$ then
$$ f(x_{k+1})-f(x_k) \ge f(x_1) - f(x_0) = f(q)-f(p) $$
Summing over $k$ from $0$ to $n-1$ gives
$$ f(x_n) \ge f(p) + n(f(q)-f(p)) $$
Since $f(q)-f(p)>0$ in the case under consideration, the RHS grows arbitrarily large as $n$ increases, showing that $f$ is not bounded.